# How to use linq to find a sub element in a list / IEnumerable?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML structure that I parse and return as an IEnumerable:

```
 <menuItem Id="1">
      <menuItem Id="2">
            <menuItem Id="5">
                  <menuItem Id="9">
                       <criterion></criterion>
                  </menuItem>
             </menuItem>
       </menuItem>
  </menuItem>
  <menuItem Id="10>
    /// huge xml document from here on...
```

I parse it using this class:

```
 public static  class XmlConverter
{

    public static IEnumerable<MenuItem> Parser()
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DataSource/MenuNavigation.xml"), FileMode.Open))
        {
            return Read(fileStream);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MenuItem> Read(Stream stream)
    {
        return (IEnumerable<MenuItem>)XmlSerializer().Deserialize(stream); ;
    }


    private static XmlSerializer XmlSerializer()
    {
        return new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MenuItem>), GetXmlRootAttribute());

    }

    private static XmlRootAttribute GetXmlRootAttribute()
    {
        return new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = "Navigation", IsNullable = true };
    }
}
```

It is parsed into this object:

```
  public class MenuItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Role")]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Alert")]
    public string Alert { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Criterion")]
    public List<Criterion> Criteria { get; set; }

    private List<MenuItem> _menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();

    [XmlElement("MenuItem")]
    public MenuItem[] MenuItems
    {
        get { return _menuItems.ToArray(); }
        set
        {
            _menuItems.Clear();
            if (value != null)
            {
                _menuItems.AddRange(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I do a Linq query on the IEnumerable that I get back I use:

```
 var criteria = menuItems.Where(x => x.Id == menuItem.Id)
                         .Select(x => x.Criteria)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is the IEnumerable here only has 14 items. Those of the parent Items so if I am looking for Id == 9 then it is not found because it is a sub element of Id 1.

How do I edit the linq statement above so that it checks each level with an element named menuItem and not just the parents for the Id in question?

Update:

The IEnumerable looks like this:

```
  Count=14
 +MenuItem //nested menuItem
  Name
```

Comment: How do you parse it? Include the code.

Comment: What does your MenuItem class look like? How does it represent its children? (And do you really have a 4-level-deep menu structure?)

Comment: Unfortunately my customer requires it be 6 deep in some places. And posting my MenuItem class now

Comment: Exactly which items are in the `IEnumerable<MenuItem>` that is returned from `XmlConverter.Parser()`? Are the nested items even present?

Comment: Yes they are present and they are nested inside I will post what the IEnumerable looks like

Comment: They are present and they are nested so if you debug the app you can follow the internal menuItems to completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `flatten` the hierarchy first (linq inherently doesn't have any support for that) - and then do what you're doing.

e.g. [How do I select recursive nested entities using LINQ to Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422735/how-do-i-select-recursive-nested-entities-using-linq-to-entity/5423024#5423024)

...and then

```
var item = menuItems.Flatten(y => y.MenuItems).Where(x => x.Id == 5)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I will look into that. I was really hoping Linq had some built in magic for it

Comment: I don't think so - you don't lose much - it enumerates - until it finds one - the only question may be in which order you'd like, depth-first etc. you can adjust that I guess.

Comment: Since I am using Xml and the document is not a million lines long it is going to be fast either way it moves through the list. I mainly have to get the code working based on his example

Comment: you shouldn't have too much menu items either way :) - yep. Since you're dealing with the linq to objects you can do such things.