# How do I programmatically determine if an XML node is a leaf node?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a big XML tree like the following:

```
<CategoryArray>
  <Category Name="Antiques" ID="20081">
    <Category Name="Antiquities" ID="37903">
      <Category Name="The Americas" ID="37908" />
      <Category Name="Byzantine" ID="162922" />
      <Category Name="Celtic" ID="162923" />
      <Category Name="Egyptian" ID="37905" />
      ...
```

I'd like to iterate through all nodes to populate a control and, when doing so, check to see: **is this node a leaft of a parent node**? What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Be careful - text nodes are nodes, too. If the document you're parsing happens to specify xml:space="preserve", your concept of a "leaf" node might change. It seems that you're really after elements that have child elements (or do not), which is technically a different concept from nodes that have child nodes (or do not).

Answer (score 6):

A leaf node is one that has no children so you can simply perform a check if it has children. There are various ways of doing this depending on how you're loading the XML document. For example, you can use the [HasChildNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmlnode.haschildnodes.aspx) property.

```
if (myXmlNode.HasChildNodes) 
    //is not a leaf  
else 
    //is a leaf
```

Answer (score 4):

Number of child nodes will give you the answer - 0 child nodes (or only text child node, depending on classes/queries you use) means it is leaf.

I.e. XElement sample form MSDN: [Find a List of Child Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675159.aspx)

```
XDocument cpo = XDocument.Load("PurchaseOrders.xml");
XElement po = cpo.Root.Element("PurchaseOrder").Element("Address");

// list1 contains all children of PurchaseOrder using  LINQ to XML query
IEnumerable<XElement> list1 = po.Elements();

// list2 contains all children of PurchaseOrder using XPath expression
IEnumerable<XElement> list2 = po.XPathSelectElements("./*");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first `flatten` the hierarchy - e.g. using the code from this post
 [How do I select recursive nested entities using LINQ to Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422735/how-do-i-select-recursive-nested-entities-using-linq-to-entity/5423024#5423024)

And then something like this...

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(this.XML)))
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(reader);

    var all = xml.Elements("Category").Flatten(x => x.Elements("Category"));
    var leafs = from cat in all
                where cat.Elements("Category").Any() == false
                select cat;

    // or go through all...
    var categories =
        from cat in all
        select new
        {
            Name = cat.Attribute("Name"),
            ID = cat.Attribute("ID"),
            IsLeaf = cat.Elements("Category").Any() == false,
            SubCount = cat.Elements("Category").Count(),
            // Subs = cat.Elements("Category").Select(x => x.Attribute("Name").ToString()).ToArray(),
        };

    // or put into dictionary etc.
    var hash = categories.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
}
```