# asp.net mvc c# listing categories recursively

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to fill a list with my categories data.
My categories have cascade format. They are formatted recursively in my database.
Here is my model object.

```
public class CategoriesDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CategoriesDTO> Subs { get; set; }
}
```

So, in my business layer, i am trying to call this method like this:

```
DAO.Categories(0);
```

it will start with "Level==0" condition and then it will go on..
but i couldn't manage the Data Access Layer. I tried this:

```
public List<CategoriesDTO> Categories(int PrmLevel)
{
    List<CategoriesDTO> DTO = new List<CategoriesDTO>();
    //DB is my dbcontext.
    DTO = DB.Categories.Select(x => new CategoriesDTO()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Level = x.Level,
        Name = x.Name
        }).Where(y => y.Level == PrmLevel).ToList();
        foreach (var item in DTO)
        {
            //im stucked
        }
        return DTO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [How do I select recursive nested entities using LINQ to Entity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5422945/2920197)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<CategoriesDTO> Categories(int PrmLevel)
{
    List<CategoriesDTO> DTO = new List<CategoriesDTO>();
    //DB is my dbcontext.
    DTO = DB.Categories.Select(x => new CategoriesDTO()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Level = x.Level,
        Name = x.Name
        }).Where(y => y.Level == PrmLevel).ToList();
        foreach (var item in DTO)
        {
            int CountSub = 0;
            CountSub = DB.Categories.Where(x => x.Level == item.Id).ToList().Count();
            if (CountSub!=0)
            {
                item.Subs = Categories(item.Id).ToList();
            }
        }
        return DTO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<CategoriesDTO> Categories(int PrmLevel)
{
    List<CategoriesDTO> DTO = new List<CategoriesDTO>();
    //DB is my dbcontext.
    DTO = DB.Categories.Select(x => new CategoriesDTO()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Level = x.Level,
        Name = x.Name
        }).Where(y => y.Level == PrmLevel).ToList();
        foreach (var item in DTO)
        {
            item.Subs = ((PrmLevel + 1) <= MaxLevel) ? Categories(PrmLevel + 1) : null;
        }
        return DTO;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi ty, btw, what do you mean with "MaxLevel"?

Comment: In my context, if Level is 0, it is a main level. http://imgur.com/a/CRqUX

Comment: @ysrtymz Well I don't know what your data looks like so I was just guessing, but hoped it would point you in the correct direction... How do you determine which records are supposed to go into the Subs List? You will need to post sample data and expected results if you want a sensible answer... You may have a look at this excellent article to get some hints: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-performance-of-traversing-a-sql-hierarchy/